# How can I change the date of a multitemporal layer on leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, layers

I am creating an app where given a certain date, the app can return the multitemporal layer of that date. Is there a way to do that in leaflet?

Comment: Can you clarify, would the date reference something pertaining to a feature(s) within the layer or to the layer itself?

Comment: the date would reference to the date of the layer (it's multitemporal), so whenever I change the date, the layer that corresponds with that date should appear on the map.

Comment: If that's the case, then it's probably just a javascript question (not a leaflet-specific issue).  In other words, I believe you could toggle a given layer's visibility based on whatever date attribute you assigned it.

Comment: I already managed to do it by adding a new layer with a different date. Thank you for your answers.